# integrate azurerm_application_gateway with AKS with terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, api-gateway, azure-aks

I  am able to create aks cluster with advance networking. able to integrate  application load balancer also with this AKS cluster  but i am unable to find any way to integrate azure api gateway with aks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application Gateway as an Ingress controller for AKS is in a beta state at the moment (as shown on the Github page - https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) and so I don't believe there will be any support for setting it up with Terraform until it gets to GA.

You might be able to do something with exec resources to set it up, but that would be up to you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no way to integrate the application load balancer with the AKS cluster directly. And you can see all the things you can set for AKS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/2018-03-31/managedclusters).

But you can integrate the application load balancer with AKS cluster when you take knowledge of [AKS internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb) and [Application gateway backend pool addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/2018-03-31/managedclusters). You can take a look at the steps that [how to integrate application gateway with AKS cluster](https://rinormaloku.com/prohibiting-direct-access-microservices-aks/).

First of all, you need to make a plan for the AKS cluster network and take an exact IP address for the application gateway backend pool address in the Terraform. Hope this will help you if there any more question you can give me the message.